# Ubuntu file ownership issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chown

I've got a problem with my forum platform being unable to install modifications, as it complains the "Packages" directory isn't writeable. It's chmodded to 0777, so it's not a permission issue, but an ownership issue.

The user www-data is part of the www-data group, and all files under /var/www/example.com are owned by www-data:www-data

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's with the downvote? If I haven't included all of the information necessary then please ask me for it, as I don't understand, that's why I'm here for help.

Comment: Also I found it unjust, thus compensated.

Comment: Are you getting this error when using apt? Can you share with us the  complete output error and the permissions under /etc/apache2?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment - it's not an answer as there's not enough information in the question to identify the issue.

> so it's not a permission issue, but an ownership issue.

Ownership *is* permissions - and if the directory is 0777 then the ownership is not the problem.

In addition to the visible file permissions, access to write a file is also subject to:

- SELinux constraints
- AppArmor contraints
- filesystem attributes
- filesystem acls
- whether the filesystem is mounted read-only

IIRC, except for the mount option, these are not enabled by default on Ubuntu - but have you checked?

Are there files inside this directory which are not writeable by the webserver uid?

What happens if you to write to the directory as the www-data user?

You did not say what the software producing the error is.

Comment: apparmor can be enabled on ubuntu by default, to disable run /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown

Comment: Hi, Thanks.

It's a Ubuntu 12.10 installation, no gui, on a VPS. Other than things I've changed, such as installing apache2, mysql, php 5.5.8, etc, I've not touched anything in your list, so they should be at default status. 

I don't know how I'd check if apache is able to write to the directory... :S